# QTCreator cannot build

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, macos-catalina

I have started a project with QTCreator and CMake but without adding anything it has a build error:

```
      Running /Users/hectoresteban/Qt/Tools/CMake/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake '-GCodeBlocks - Ninja' /Users/hectoresteban/Documents/C++/Qt/trial in /Users/hectoresteban/Documents/C++/Qt/trial/build.
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/hectoresteban/Documents/C++/Qt/trial/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
CMake process exited with exit code 1.
Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

What should I do? I do not want to build it with Ninja but with a normal Unix Makefile but I do not know how to change the `build` settings
The initial `CMakeLists.txt` is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(trial LANGUAGES CXX)
set(ANDROID_NDK_ROOT "/Users/hectoresteban/Documents/C++/Qt/android-ndk-r21d")

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core LinguistTools REQUIRED)

set(TS_FILES trial_en_DE.ts)

add_executable(trial
  main.cpp
  ${TS_FILES}
)
target_link_libraries(trial Qt5::Core)

qt5_create_translation(QM_FILES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} ${TS_FILES})
```

Comment: ... Did you set the `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT` environment variable as the error message asks you to?

Comment: to what should I set it to?

Comment: It should point to the directory where you installed your Android NDK

Comment: I have editted but still have issues with the Ninja stuff

Comment: Did you `brew install ninja`?

Comment: but cannot I use the normal make?

Comment: Sure you can, just drop the `"-GCodeBlocks - Ninja"`  argument to CMake.

Comment: Could you point me how to change the build command? In "Projects" I cannot find where the remove the "-GCodeBlocks - Ninja" from the build command

Comment: If you're building using qt creator, does it matter that much whether the underlying tool is make or ninja? It should be available as a different generator, but may require setting up kits or some such.